# problem while checking if an element exist in an array

Tags: javascript

i was traying to do the odin project exercises of javascript,

when I execute this line in the console
`2 in [2,3,4,5]`
it gives
`true`

but when I execute `3 in [3,4,5]` in the console it gives back `false` I think it should also be true!!!

any explanation please
thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) means what you think it means - it's not looking for a value, but a property (or index). Seems like you might want [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator checks if a *property key* exists on an object. You can think of this array as having 4 keys.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 5];
// arr has the keys `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`.
console.log(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
```

So when you have the expression `2 in arr`, you are checking if the array has a *key* `2`, **not** if the *value* `2` exists in the array.

If you do want to check if an array contains an item, the [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method would achieve what you want.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.includes(2); // true
arr.includes(0); // false
```

Comment: now I get it, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It behaves like this because the `in` operator returns `true` if the specified property (not value) is in the specified object.

So in the first case the array has a length of 4 with indices 0,1,2,3 so the element with the index 2 exists.

In the second case there are 3 elements with indices 0,1,2, so there is no element with an index 3 that is why it returns `false`.